# Implementating a logical parser in django-query

Tags: django, django-queryset, logical-operators

This is going to be a "long one".  I'm including as much code and explanation as possible ... I'm not above throwing out code if necessary.

I'm trying to implement a logical parser in a django query system.  Where users can provide complex queries against tags that are applied to samples.  This is essentially part of a scientific sample repository where users can apply defined tags (tissue-type, disease studied, etc.).  They can then create persistent "baskets" of samples defined by a logical query on these tags.

```
#models.py

class Sample(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)


class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    samples = models.ManyToManyField(Sample)

A quick example:
#example data:
Sample1 has TagA, TagB, TagC
Sample2 has       TagB, TagC, TagD
Sample3 has TagA,       TagC, TagD
Sample4 has       TagB

#example query:
'TagB AND TagC AND NOT TagD'
```

would return Sample1.  I use a crazy string-eval hack to create a set of `Q()` objects:

```
def MakeQObject(expression):
    """
    Takes an expression and uses a crazy string-eval hack to make the qobjects.
    """
    log_set = {'AND':'&','OR':'|','NOT':'~'}

    exp_f = []
    parts = expression.split()
    #if there is a ) or ( then we can't use this shortcut
    if '(' in parts or ')' in parts:
        return None

    for exp in parts:
        if exp in log_set:
            exp_f.append(log_set[exp])
        else:
            exp_f.append("Q(tags__name__iexact = '%s')" % exp)
    st = ' '.join(exp_f)
    qobj = eval(st)
    return qobj
```

However, this fails on anything that needs a complicated order of operations or grouping by ().  Given the same example data the query: `(TagA OR TagB) AND NOT TagD` should return Sample1, Sample4 but does not.  I've implemented a "one-at-a-time" function which can take a single Sample object and perform the query.  However, in my actual database I have ~40,000 Samples and ~400 tags (about ~7 per Sample) and the iterative technique takes ~4 minutes to complete on all Samples.  So I calculate the baskets nightly and then just freeze them during the day.  I worry that as I start curating more baskets, samples and tags this will scale poorly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: i've also tried "factoring" the `()` type queries into longer but equivalent versions without parens but haven't been able to make those work either.

Answer (score 1):

First, to improve performance it will *probably* help to add an index on tag name field since you are using it for queries.  So, add **db_index=True** to your column:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, db_index=True)
    samples = models.ManyToManyField(Sample)
```

Second, for parsing the user queries I would recommend using one of several good Python-based parsers such as [PyParsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) or [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/).  These might seem intimidating at first but really aren't that hard, especially with a simple grammar such as yours.

If those are too much for you, then try rolling your own using Fredrik's guide [Simple Top-Down Parsing in Python](http://effbot.org/zone/simple-top-down-parsing.htm).

Comment: Additional note: you need to reset your database for db_index to be seen by syncdb.  If you can't reset then you need to manually add the index yourself to the database or use a migration tool such as South (http://south.aeracode.org/).

Comment: Thanks Van ... I think I can probably use their example for simple math expressions "http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/fourFn.py".  Just replace the `math.operations` with queryset operations and then let it take care of the nesting, etc.